# How to create scroll view programmatically?

Tags: android, widget

I want to create scroll view with text view inside it programmatically. My code is like below. It works, but when I do getLayoutParams in onSizeChanged, I get InvocationTargetException. What is wrong with my code?

```
public MyActivity extends Activity 
  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyLayout(this));
    }
    protected class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout 
     {
        TextView tv;
        public MyLayout(Context context)
        {
           super(context);
           ScrollView sv = ScrollView(context);
           tv = new TextView(context);
           tv.setText("Hello World");
           sv.addView(tv);
           addView(sv);
        }
        protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
        {
            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams(); // I have          InvocationTargetException here. What's wrong?
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put some text in that TextView, so:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyLayout(this));
    }
    protected class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(context);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("Hello World");
        sv.addView(tv);
        addView(sv);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: well, my last edit worked, maybe it's something in your real code you that's different

Comment: Right. It works. I edited my code. But the problem is when I call getLayouParams in onSizeChanged, I get error. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Because you haven't supplied any `LayoutParams` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `LayoutParams` for both `View`s - the `ScrollView` and the `TextView`. And use the correct type (`FrameLayout.LayoutParams` for both).

E.g.

```
...
tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("Hello World");
sv.addView(tv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollview should not use wrap_content but fill_parent.